# Selenium Error - platform_sensor_reader_win.cc(242)]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]I have been having issues with my selenium and chromedriver that I can't seem to figure out. I have one code that runs just fine and does everything it is supposed to. However, I have another that give me the error code in the picture. If anyone could help, I would certainly appreciate it as I had no luck finding anything online. I especially don't understand why one program runs with no issues and the other doesn't.

Code that runs just fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

beginningTime = time.time()
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(3)

browser.get('http://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/Data/DataDownload/ComprehensiveStatistics.aspx')
browser.maximize_window()
dropdown = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="dnn_ctr1009_USDMservice_CompStats_2017_aoiType_chosen"]""")
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


beginningTime = time.time()
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
symbols = ['WYNN', 'FL', 'TTWO', 'NKE']
myColumnHeaders = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

dfs = []

for c in range(len(symbols)):
    browser.get('https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/'+symbols[c]+'/historical')
    print('read url')
    time.sleep(3)
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    print('here')
```

It prints 'read url' and opens the webpage but never gets to the print 'here' step. It then throws the note in the command prompt that is attached as a picture. Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the website has restricted the use of selenium somehow as I tried a couple other websites and they load. If so, does anyone know of a workaround. I'm trying to get 5 years of stock data but their website defaults to 3 months.

Answer (score -1):

```
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe',
                              chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22792983).